# Passing 'unsigned short[8]' to parameter of type 'CHAR16 *' (aka 'short *') converts between pointers to integer types with different sign

Tags: c, ansi-c, uefi

I have the following code:

```
//#include "stdint.h"

#include "uefi.h"
//#include "efi_libs.h"

void PrintLn(CHAR16* String, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE* _SystemTable);
void Print(CHAR16* String, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE* _SystemTable);

EFI_STATUS efi_main(EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE* _SystemTable)
{
    //    SystemTable = _SystemTable;

    _SystemTable->ConOut->Reset(_SystemTable->ConOut, 1);
    _SystemTable->ConIn->Reset(_SystemTable->ConIn, 1);
    _SystemTable->ConOut->SetAttribute(_SystemTable->ConOut, EFI_GREEN);

    Print(L"Welcome", _SystemTable);
    PrintLn(L"Press any key to continue...", _SystemTable);

    EFI_INPUT_KEY key;
    while (_SystemTable->ConIn->ReadKeyStroke(_SystemTable->ConIn, &key) == EFI_NOT_READY);

    return EFI_SUCCESS;
}

void Print(CHAR16* String, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE* _SystemTable)
{
    _SystemTable->ConOut->OutputString(_SystemTable->ConOut, String);
}

void PrintLn(CHAR16* String, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE* _SystemTable)
{
    _SystemTable->ConOut->OutputString(_SystemTable->ConOut, String);
    _SystemTable->ConOut->OutputString(_SystemTable->ConOut, L"\r\n");
}
```

And I am getting this warning when compiling it:

> ```
> src/efi_main.c:17:8: warning: passing 'unsigned short[8]' to parameter of type 'CHAR16 *' (aka 'short *') converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
>         Print(L"Welcome", _SystemTable);
>               ^~~~~~~~~~
> src/efi_main.c:7:20: note: passing argument to parameter 'String' here
> void Print(CHAR16* String, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE* _SystemTable);
>                    ^
> ```

Now it has been many years since I wrote ANSI C, and I have no idea how to eradicate the warning, can someone please explain the warning to me and show me how t fix it?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: A pointer to a `signed short` (which is what plain `short` is) is not the same as a pointer to a `unsigned short`.

Comment: Are you using EDK2, gnu-efi or your own UEFI framework? Can you post your compiler command line call?

Comment: My own framework

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. Yes the message is pretty clear but understanding why I am getting the warning is not and nor is how to fix it.

Comment: Then please show us your typedef for CHAR16 this should be unsigned short.

Comment: Your `Print` accepts a pointer to a `CHAR16` i.e. `short` i.e. `signed short`. However, `L"Welcome"` produces a pointer to a `wchar_t` i.e. `unsigned short`. So you attempt to pass an `unsigned short *` into a `signed short *` argument, hence the warning.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a comment in the code on the line where you get the error.

Comment: typedef signed short int CHAR16;

Comment: @MiSimon add that as the answer it fixed the problem!

Comment: You need to use unsigned short for CHAR16.

Comment: When you say "Now it has been many years since I wrote ANSI C," should we understand that to mean you are trying to program in ANSI C (a.k.a. C89) *now*?  It doesn't actually make much difference, but ANSI C is about 30 years out of date.  C17 is current, and C2X is imminent.  If you're genuinely trying to restrict yourself to ANSI C then that may require extra work.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Print` accepts a pointer to a `CHAR16` i.e. `short` i.e. `signed short`. However, `L"Welcome"` produces a pointer to a `wchar_t` i.e. `unsigned short`. So you attempt to pass an `unsigned short *` into a `signed short *` argument, hence the warning.

The solution is therefore to either change the string-related functions to accept `wchar_t *` instead of `CHAR16 *` arguments (which would make sense given that `L` string literals emit a `wchar_t[]`) or to change the typedef of `CHAR16` to be compatible by making it `unsigned` instead of `signed`.

Answer (score 1):

> Now it has been many years since I wrote ANSI C, and I have no idea how to eradicate the warning, can someone please explain the warning to me and show me how t fix it?

#### Nature of the warning

The warning's descriptive text is:

> warning: passing 'unsigned short[8]' to parameter of type 'CHAR16 ' (aka 'short ') converts between pointers to integer types with different sign

That is accompanied by marked-up code excerpts that show exactly where the mismatch appears.  In particular, the offending argument is the wide-string literal `L"Welcome"` in the line ...

> ```
>     Print(L"Welcome", _SystemTable);`
> ```

... and the corresponding parameter is `String` in ...

> ```
> void Print(CHAR16* String, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE* _SystemTable);
> ```

.

Wide string literals expressed with the `L` prefix represent arrays of `wchar_t`, whose details are implementation defined.  Apparently, your implementation defines it as [`signed`] `short int`.

`CHAR16` is your own thing, apparently defined as or expanding to `unsigned short int`.

Like any array would be, the wide string literal is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element (type `short int *`) where it appears in the function call expression.  The corresponding parameter has type `unsigned short int *`.  **These types differ in the signedness of their pointed-to types**, and that's exactly what the warning is telling you.

#### Significance of the warning

This warning is calling your attention to a comparatively benign situation.  The two pointer types involved are "compatible" in the formal sense of the C language spec, and, given the types as defined, reading the elements of the string literal via a pointer of type `unsigned short int *` is allowed.  Technically, there is a potential that such reads might not produce what you expect, but in practice, you are unlikely to be targeting a platform where that could be the case.

#### Other issues

There are some potentially more significant issues here, however.

- Most importantly, although [wide] string literals do not technically have elements of `const`-qualified type, attempts to modify their elements nevertheless produce undefined behavior.  On many systems, that usually manifests as a crash.  On others, various other types of unwanted behavior can manifest. To avoid risk of unintentionally trying to perform such modifications, pointers to string literal elements should be declared as pointers to `const`, and `const`-correctness should be maintained.  Example: `void consume_wide_string_literal(const wchar_t *wide_string);`
- The `wchar_t` data type of wide string literal elements is not necessarily a 16-bit type.  Although it often is 16 bits, C allows it to be either wider or narrower (consistently for a given C implementation).  If you want an integer type that C itself guarantees is exactly 16 bits wide then you may have options:

  - If you can rely on at least C99, or if your compiler provides them as an extension, then `int16_t` and its unsigned analog `uint16_t`, both declared in `stdint.h`, are integer types exactly 16 bits wide, with no padding bits, the former represented in two's complement format, supposing the implementation has any such types at all.  However, this does not directly help you with `L`-style wide string literals if `wchar_t` is wider or narrower than 16 bits.
  - If you are prepared to rely on C11 or later then you could also choose `char16_t` (defined in `uchar.h`) and wide string literals prefixed with `u` instead of `L`.

#### How to fix it

You have multiple options for fixing it, varying in complexity.

- ***Don't***: these particular warnings may well be highlighting an issue that is strictly hypothetical for you.  You have the option of just accepting that the compiler will report them.  This has the advantage that if you ever decide that you want or need to really fix them then the compiler will still be telling you where to look.
- ***Disable the warning in question***.  From the form of the diagnostic, you appear to be compiling with GCC or with a compiler that emulates its diagnostics and options.  I anticipate that if you add the option `-Wno-pointer-sign` to your compiler command line then it will stop reporting any diagnostics in this category.  That has the advantage that it will genuinely silence the warnings without requiring code changes, and the disadvantage that it may also silence other warnings in the same category that you actually wanted to see.
- ***Cast***: cast the wide string literal to the type of the function parameter:

  ```
      Print((CHAR16 *) L"Welcome", _SystemTable);
  ```

  That should silence the warnings, but if they are relevant to a real underlying problem then this just masks the issue.  It doesn't actually *fix* anything.
- ***Create pseudo-literals of type `CHAR16[]`***, and use those.  For example:

  ```
      static const union {
          wchar_t as_wchar[sizeof(L"Welcome") / sizeof(wchar_t)];
          CHAR16  as_char16[sizeof(L"Welcome") / sizeof(wchar_t)];
      } welcome = { L"Welcome" };

      Print(welcome.as_char16, _SystemTable);
  ```

  If you really wanted to pursue this approach, then you might also want to create a macro to generate such declarations for you. Be aware that this will likely force you to engage with the question of `const`ness.
- ***Fix the functions / CHAR16 datatype***: it's unclear what other kind of adjustments might be needed, but where you want functions to be compatible with arguments that are wide string literals (of any flavor) then the *best* way would be to assign types to their parameters that are consistent with that objective.  That might mean changing your `CHAR16` to `wchar_t`, or perhaps to `char16_t` if you want to rely on a compiler supporting that.  I would also recommend doing away with the type alias or macro `CHAR16`, whichever it is, and using the the chose standard type.  Also, use `const` qualification for those function parameters that should accept string literals.